# Javascript: DOM Exception Error with AppendChild

Tags: javascript

Why i get an error ? I just want to add 'a' to the div. Not remplace, but add.

```html
var conteneur1 = document.getElementsByClassName('conteneur')[0];
      conteneur1.appendChild('a');
```

I have: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a node in a context where it doesn't exist. Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think it's not correct way to append child. Try the code below:

```
var anchorEl = document.createElement('a');
var textOfLink = document.createTextNode("YourText");

anchorEl.appendChild(textOfLink);
anchorEl.title = "YourLink";
anchorEl.href = "http://YourLink.com";

var conteneur1 = document.getElementsByClassName('conteneur')[0];
      conteneur1.appendChild(anchorEl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just pass a string to [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), you have to pass a node element.

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of
>   children of a specified parent node.

```
var conteneur1 = document.getElementsByClassName('conteneur')[0];
var a = document.createElement('a');
conteneur1.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is simply passing a string as an argument **.appendChild()** does not accept string.

this should fix it.

```
    var conteneur1 = document.getElementsByClassName('conteneur')[0];
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    conteneur1.appendChild(a);
```

See here [w3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)